# function loadMeals() in TableViewController not working

Tags: swift

I am new to Xcode. I am practicing this official tutorial from apple - https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/PersistData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH14-SW1

The loadView() function in MealTableViewController does not work. The full code for MealTableViewontroller link is https://github.com/askit5/FoodTracker/blob/master/FoodTracker/MealTableViewController.swift

I want to add a list from MealViewcontroller, which is source viewcontroller to MealTableviewcontroller.
I have uploaded the project on github -
https://github.com/askit5/FoodTracker

**Now, I have got 2 problems**

**Problem 1**)

When I click on "Save" button of MealViewController - see link in Github https://github.com/askit5/FoodTracker/blob/master/Screenshot%20%20of%20MealViewController.png - the new meals do not get added to the MealtableViewController(other than savedmeals i.e. meals already present) -
                    https://github.com/askit5/FoodTracker/blob/master/Screenshot%20of%20MealTableViewController.png

I am also linking the screenshot of the storyboard - https://github.com/askit5/FoodTracker/blob/master/Screenshot%20of%20storyboard.png

**Problem 2**)

When I click on the "+" button on in the MealTableViewController, it shows the following error (linking the screenshot of the error) - https://github.com/askit5/FoodTracker/blob/master/Screenshot%20of%20second%20error.png

I have less than 10 points. So, I cannot add screenshots in stackoverflow. Therefore, I have linked the project and also the screenshots in the GitHub. Please help.

here is one of the problem - the - "@IBAction func unwindToMealList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {}" function in MealTableViewController  is not linked to the "save" button(i.e. the dot is not flled) . I tried everything, but no avail.

Comment: too many link xD

Comment: I suggest to review your code because is very confused. Is a good approach to add some comments in the code, describe the functions and the variables otherwise could be very hard to understand the functionality. When I run you project, and I try to add an new Item the button is always disabled and there is no way to assign an image to the new item. Are you sure the project is updated?

Comment: here is one of the problem - the - "@IBAction func unwindToMealList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {}" function in MealTableViewController  is not linked to the "save" button(i.e. the dot is not flled) . I tried everything, but no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your identifier matches your segue

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Problem2.
If you look in the Interface Builder, the "connection" between the "+" and the ViewController has not a name.

[image]

You have to define the segue name using the Storyboard Segue Identifier.
To assign the name, click on the connection and define a valid name: in the picture an example:

[image].

In your code you must check if the segue identifier matches the segue identifier defined in the Interface Builder. In your case you have to specify the name "AddItem"